# Why doesn't the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ exist on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, area-51, stack-exchange-button

[image]

Aside from the "gen-u-wine™" thing I actually want to have the global-inbox enabled in Area 51 (maybe http://stackexchange.com too).

Comment: Prolonged exposure to the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is not a part of this test.

Comment: +1, I was about to ask this myself.

Comment: Isn't that spelt `gen-u-whine`?

Comment: @Chacha: The StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™ refers to the global tag-set feature. This is different from the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ here.

Comment: +1 For dashed freehand cirlce.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We *finally* just added the gen-u-wine™ StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ to Area 51! Sorry that took so long.

Answer (score 3):

As to the why, Area 51 does not have an API.  While this does not mean they couldn't show the data from the other sites that do have an API, I suspect it is omitted to try and avoid confusion.

Comment: Meh, I doubt this is the reason. Looking at the ajax request pulled by that thing, you can see that it's making requests to `http://stackexchange.com/genuwine` for hot questions and sites, and `sitename/inbox/genuwine` for the inbox, so it has nothing to do with the site specific API. I think it's far more likely because A51's codebase branched off before that button was added, and the team never bothered to update it to add the button.

Comment: @YiJiang, I think it would be a bit confusing to have the inbox there but not have it showing activity from A51.

Comment: That's would be a reason why activities from A51 doesn't show up, not why the button doesn't exist. Also, I doubt that's the reason. The lack of an API simply means the team doesn't see a need to publish one, not necessarily because the data isn't there.

Comment: @YiJiang, obviously I'm not in a position to speak officially on this.  I really have no idea!

Comment: It's been months, and guess what? Now you *are* in a position to speak officially on this, haha~

Answer (score -1):

I think they have not yet figure out how to integrate the two different types of sites they have created.  Area 51 draws on the other accounts differently than a usual stack exchange account.  Maybe they just haven't got a coder to the problem, or they are waiting for more data on the issue.