# Put StackExchange menu on Area51 as well

Tags: feature-request, area-51, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ doesn't exist on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-doesnt-exist-on-area51)

The StackExchange menu in the upper left is quite useful for navigating the Stack Exchange sites, but the Area51 site does not have it.  Could it be added so users can return to other SE sites via a link, rather than using the back button or a bookmark?

Comment: MultiCollider SuperDropdown is certainly not something I would have thought to search for.

Comment: Well, that's crazy. What *else* could you possibly call it?