# Add the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ to StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, stackexchange.com

I know the popup menu is basically a condensed version of stackexchange.com but I miss the little red icon and the inbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ doesn't exist on Area51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-doesnt-exist-on-area51) (Specifically the last line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was completed a few weeks ago, but we forgot to update this question.