# Notifications are missing from global inbox on StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, stackexchange.com

I don't know if the new [Notifications](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) haven't yet been [pushed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68670/add-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-to-stackexchange-com) to [stackexchange.com](http://s.tk) but they should be IMHO.

Comment: umm... @Emmett This is status-completed right?