# Why is there no StackExchange inbox on Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ doesn't exist on Area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-doesnt-exist-on-area51)

Why is there no StackExchange inbox on Area51? Am I missing it somewhere?

Comment: Go vote up [Why the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ doesn't exist on Area51?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-doesnt-exist-on-area51).

Comment: @Dori - Good catch. I missed it because I didn't realize that the SE inbox had that name, "MultiColliderSuperDropDown". I've voted to close.