# Why does area51 not link to stackexchange.com as the other sites do?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, stackexchange.com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™  exist on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-doesnt-the-stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-exist-on-area-51)

Why is area51 the only one site not having the little stackexchange.com link and drop-down widget in the top? I sometimes want to research the fate of promoted sites and have to navigate to stackexchange.com using the URL bar.