# Area 51 is missing the StackExchange notification pop-up

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™  exist on Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/why-doesnt-the-stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-exist-on-area-51)

I love the pop-up that is in the very center of this screenshot:
[image]

I know Area 51 is very special, but despite that it should include the notification pop-up. I don't know if this is a bug, or if it is invisible, but it should be there:
[image]

Is there a special reason for it not being there, is it laziness or did Jeff just forgot to implement it?

Comment: @Grace whoops, didn't notice. Mmm... notice...